# Does Java JVM use pthread?

Tags: java, linux, macos, jvm, pthreads

Does JVM on Mac OS X use pthread to create threads?

What about on Linux distributions, is it now default way to create threads for JVM on all distributions?

Comment: You need to specify *which* JVM (vendor and version) to make this question meaningful. The Java Language Specification nor the Java Virtual Machine Specification require any particular named thread implementation; they just require Java to follow the threading semantics of the JVM spec (including the Java Memory Model). However - here's a blog post that goes into some detail (this blog post also assumes that every JVM comes from Oracle which isn't true) http://blog.narmnevis.com/2010/11/how-does-jvm-map-a-java-thread-to-a-native-thread/

Comment: Oracle Java 8 JVM on OSX Yosemete, Debian, Ubuntu?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, HotSpot JVM (i.e. Oracle JDK and OpenJDK) uses `pthreads` on [Linux](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/8b16790cd73a/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp#l855) and on [Mac OS X](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/8b16790cd73a/src/os/bsd/vm/os_bsd.cpp#l816).

Comment: Do you have a reference for that claim?

Comment: @EJP The references to the HotSpot source code are in the answer, just follow the links.